# How to read ArrayList data Which is existed in InputStream?

Tags: android

I am new to android application development.
I am developing one android application, which is interact with servlet.The servlet send back response in the form of ArrayList.

In my android application i receive the Array List data using input Stream.

My requirement is How to get the ArrayList data from InputStream

Please help me to go forward.

thank you,
bye.

Answer (score 0):

Try receiving it using a Buffered Reader and adding each line to a new ArrayList you create.